# How to increase the speed of cypher queries in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have established a Neo4J database with 14k nodes and 15k relationships. When I run this query:

```
  MATCH (n:RealNode {gid:'12'})<-[:contains*..4]->(z) RETURN DISTINCT ID(z), z.id,n.id as InternalID
```

it takes more than 5 secs to get a response. If I change 4 to 10 it takes much more.

I attach a screenshot of the nodes and relations for a specific node:

[image]

My n:RealNode is the pink one and the nodes with the CONTAINS relation are the grey ones.

My questions are the following: 
1) How can I optimize the speed of the queries (apart from indexes).
2) Would it make a difference in the speed if I have all the grey nodes under the pink node directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you stated "apart from the indexes" I assume you have a correct schema index for :RealNode(gid)

However your query will not make use of indexes because you MATCH on an entire pattern (valid for Neo4j<2.2M04)

You can better split the query by first matching the part you know :

```
MATCH (n:RealNode {gid:'12'})
MATCH (n)-[:contains*..4]-(z) RETURN DISTINCT ID(z), z.id,n.id as InternalID
```

Also I removed the arrows from the path, there is no need to set it on both sides, just omit them.

If you still have performance problems, please share **version** you are using, **JAVA heap settings**, and the **PROFILE** output of the query in neo4j-shell

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What you suggest, to execute two different queries its not possible  as I execute the query through a web app (by sending a post request) and I need the response as is now. But if this is the only solution maybe I should change the code. Also does the arrows affect the speed? And if yes how? I set on both sides cause some of the nodes have different directions.  My neo4j verion is 2.1.6.

Comment: Christophe's snippet is not two queries, it's one query having two matches being chained together.

Comment: In any case this query doesnt return the same result with mine.

Comment: Please provide the profile output of both queries then. So we can better debug and help